# SFMC Inbox marking message as Read status clears all notifications from the notification tray on iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification, inbox

We are using mobile studio to send Inbox Push notification with Alert + Inbox, the push notification arrives fine and we can call `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_getUnreadMessages()` to retrieve the unRead inbox message.

The issue we're having is all the push notification (including the non inbox message ones) in the notification tray on iOS gets cleared when we called any of the functions...

- `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_markMessage(withIdRead: id)`
- `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_markAllMessagesRead()`
- `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_markMessageRead(messageDictionary: inboxMsg)`

...to try to mark the unRead message as Read status.

We don't want any of the push notifications in the push notification tray deleted when marking an inbox message as Read.

MarkingCloudSDK (7.6.0) is used in our projects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please open a support ticket and @mention ppattabiraman@salesforce.com and bmote@salesforce.com Thanks,
Prakashini